# How to add list of widget inside a nested list Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Since `List.generate()` take `List<Widget>` as parameter, how do you assign `List<Widget>` inside a nested List?

example List:

```
List<List<List<dynamic>>> questions = [
  [['a?','00:00:00', 'Mulai Pekerjaan', '00:00', false, true], <Widget>[]],
  [['b?','00:00:00', 'Mulai Pekerjaan', '00:00', false, true], <Widget>[]],
  [['c?','00:00:00', 'Mulai Pekerjaan', '00:00', false, true], <Widget>[]],
  [['d?','00:00:00', 'Mulai Pekerjaan', '00:00', false, true], <Widget>[]],
  [['e?','00:00:00', 'Mulai Pekerjaan', '00:00', false, true], <Widget>[]],
  [['f?','00:00:00', 'Mulai Pekerjaan', '00:00', false, true], <Widget>[]],
  [['g?','00:00:00', 'Mulai Pekerjaan', '00:00', false, true], <Widget>[]],
  [['h?','00:00:00', 'Mulai Pekerjaan', '00:00', false, true], <Widget>[]],
  [['i?','00:00:00', 'Mulai Pekerjaan', '00:00', false, true], <Widget>[]],
];
```

List generate:

```
List.generate(questions[index][1].length, (index) => _time(size, index, textStyle))),
```

Error: 'The element type '`List<Widget>`' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.

Comment: It would be better if you will create a `Question` class so that your list will be `List<Question>`. Also, `Question` should not have a list of widget property. You should create a widget that uses the `Question`'s properties and it will automatically adapt.

Comment: Can I push a widget to the Widget array if I model the data that way? @rickimaru

Comment: No need to add a `Widget` array in your `Question` class. Just create a `Widget` in your screen that uses the `Question` object. If you design it properly, it should be reusable. (I still don't know how your UI looks like though, it would be better if you will add the UI design in your question)